# How can one get better at copywriting?

Tags: resources, marketing, education, copywriting

Since copy is such a key part of a startup's website, many business people would like to learn to be good copywriters personally.  Such a person would need to be a good persuasive writer, and able to convey information about their product or service very concisely.

If someone whose primary background is not writing wanted to learn to be a great copywriter, what resources would you recommend they use? Free and paid resources are fair game.

Comment: I found that a one/two day technical writing course early in my career was very beneficial.  Most of it can be summed up by the goal of: do the work yourself so your readers don't have to work.

Answer (score 5):

This might sound strange, but being a copywriter isn't really about WRITING. It's about persuasion.

Read books on rhetoric, argument, and logic. This will teach you the basic underlying structure of persuasive communication.

Listen to great speeches by influential people. This will let you see with your own eyes how basic rhetorical techniques are used to persuade and inspire. TED Talks is a great resource for speeches. I also have a particular soft spot for Daniel Dennett.

Research psychology and neuroscience and how these disciplines are used in marketing. This will teach you how rhetorical techniques affect our brains. Understanding brain science will help you use your powers of persuasion more effectively (and responsibly).

Comment: I was kind of hoping someone else had already done that and was willing to share or even sell it. ;-) I don't want to be a professional copywriter, let alone a copywriting researcher. Who has gone before me from whom I may learn?

Comment: oh! Have you checked out this site? http://www.copyblogger.com/copywriting-101/

Comment: that is perfect. Any others?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

[Influence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006124189X) by Robert Caldini

[The AdWeek Copywriting Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470051248) by Joseph Sugarman

I have other books on my shelf, but have not read them, so cannot recommend them yet.

Comment: I also recommend Write to Sell by Andy Maslen